# Extracting data from a calendar with Python and Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to get data in a calendar:

http://www.purebhakti.com/component/panjika

I thought about using Python and beautifulsoap but I accept suggestions.

I would like to take the event of the day:

22 Apr 2017 : Ekādaśī, K, 06:09, Śatabhiṣā

+ŚUDDHA EKĀDAŚĪ VRATA: FASTING FOR Varūthinī EKADASI

How to make the program reach the calendar (after making the time zone and city selection automatically)? For example:
Time zone = -3:00 Buenos Aires
city = Rio de Janeiro

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'http://www.purebhakti.com/component/panjika'
header = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) '
                        'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                        'Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36'}



req = requests.get(url,headers= header)

html = req.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
```

Comment: Did you try anything ? What's your effort so far ?

Comment: I dont know what to find the elements that I want to select in the web page!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import requests, bs4
from urllib.parse import parse_qsl

qs = 'action=2&timezone=23&location=Rio+de+Janeiro%2C+Brazil++++++++043W15+22S54+++++-3.00&button=Get+Calendar'
payload = dict(parse_qsl(qs))
r = requests.post('http://www.purebhakti.com/component/panjika', data=payload)
```

when you click the button, you are posting data to server, you can find the data in chrome development tool.

[image]

we can mimic this behavior via `requests.post()`

I also use `parse_qsl` to convert encoded url to python dict:

```
{'action': '2',
'button': 'Get Calendar',
 'location': 'Rio de Janeiro, Brazil        043W15 22S54     -3.00',
 'timezone': '23'}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried to understand the code. What is "date"? data' is not defined. Could you help me, please?

Comment: @Ed S when you use post, you are sending data to the server, it's a dict contains the k-v pairs.http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests

Comment: payload = dict(parse_qsl(data))
NameError: name 'data' is not defined

Comment: @Ed S my bad, I update the code and feel free to accept my answer

Comment: I am very newbie in programming. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to solve this question:

-You can use Selenium WebDriver to click on a button and select time-zone and city.

-Another option than Selenium is to use pyautogui ("pyautogui.locateOnScreen" function).

-To download calendar (webpage source) use urllib2

-To get necessary data from calendar, use Beautiful Soap

Comment: He is using python 3. In python 3 there is no module named urllib2.

Comment: @KhairulBasarRofi You're right. There is: urllib.request module.